# What does the "scroll" box after a node mean in DOM inspector?

Tags: firefox, dom, scroll, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I noticed while inspecting a document that at some point, a square box with `scroll` appears next to it.

Unlike `event` box, clicking on it doesn't trigger anything.
I first thought it just means a scroll event is attached to the node element, but as there are many scroll related events under the `event` box, it must be something else.

[image: scroll box]

What does the `scroll` box after a node mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `scroll` marker means that the element is a scroll container and its content overflows its viewport. There is a short tooltip indicating that:

[image: Element with scrollable overflow]

Because there was no documentation for that on MDN, I have now created a [table describing all possible markers](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#node-markers).

Comment: The tooltip appears automatically when you hover the `scroll` marker and stay there for a second. If it doesn't appear, it is most probably missing in the translation of your Firefox.